# Using regex module with pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can I use the regex module (as it supports non-fixed-length lookbehind assertions) with str.contains() to find matches within a pandas Series? The code below returns the following error, I guess because it uses the re module: `TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern`.

```
import pandas as pd
import regex
to_test = pd.Series([ 'yes' , 'no' , 'yes' ])
classifier = regex.compile(r"yes")
result = to_test.str.contains(classifier)
```

Comment: It expects a `re` object, not `regex`.

Comment: is there a way to use a `regex` object?

Comment: Yes, if you define your own method and use `.apply`

Comment: i'll do that then, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define your own method like `regex_search` and use `apply()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import regex

to_test = pd.Series([ 'yes' , 'no' , 'yes' ])

def regex_contains(s, rx):
    return bool(rx.search(s))

classifier = regex.compile(r"yes")
to_test.apply(regex_contains, args=(classifier,))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```